# How to use React as external package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm making a small app which will be included to another bigger project(let's call it the Main project) as a external package.
I'm using "Create React App" for it.

It works fine, but I want to build my app without including React to the bundle file because the Main project will also have React as a dependency for another purposes.

Now I'm trying next:

1. I have run "eject" script on my project so now I have an access to the webpack configs.
2. In the webpack.config.dev.js file I've added next property:

   ```
   externals: {
     react: {
       root: 'React',
       commonjs2: 'react',
       commonjs: 'react',
       amd: 'react',
       umd: 'react',
     },
     'react-dom': {
       root: 'ReactDOM',
       commonjs2: 'react-dom',
       commonjs: 'react-dom',
       amd: 'react-dom',
       umd: 'react-dom',
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now, as I understand, I need to include React and ReactDom to my index.html which is in the public folder.

In the body tag I included two scripts from React CDN:

https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

But when I run npm start it doesn't work and throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

How can I configure "Create React App" to exclude React from the bundle?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is not possible, and I don't understand why you try to do this? Can you maybe show an example of what you mean by this project that is included? Is this just another react app in an react app?

Comment: Have you taken a look here? https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-an-existing-app.html

Comment: @Larce The "Main project" is a PIXI application and I'm making the UI for it with React: buttons, menu, etc. But also I want to add another React app to the Main project, which will provide, for an example, the dialog service. And I thought that it is a good idea adding React as a dependency to the Main project to avoid a duplication of react code...

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped you? Remember to mark it as the "accepted answer" if it does.

Comment: Hi @JorgeFuentesGonzález. Yes, your solution if perfect. Unfortunately I cannot vote for your answer because my "reputation is " less then 15 :(

Comment: @AlexeyRozumovsky Nice, I'm glad it works! ^^ Below 15 reputation you can accept the answer by clickng the checkmark below the vote bottons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
externals: {
  react: 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
}
```

Also, don't add them to the body tag. Add them to the head. And finally, they must be added before your bundle file.

Comment: thank you. It seems that it works :) Will try to the same for production build.

Comment: `don't add them to the body tag. Add them to the head` -- not sure this is right unless I'm missing something specific to webpack externals, best practice is adding scripts at bottom of body tag to avoid blocking any other content while loading. Order matters, yes, but bottom of body should be where you put them.

Comment: Of course @davnicwil, but your script should not access reactdom and react until all scripts are loaded, so you need to add extra listeners. And with react you won't see any HTML until you use the react library, so is kinda useless to add them at the end to avoid blocking content loading, as you won't draw something until they both are loaded. Adding them to the head (before your script, forgot about this detail) you avoid waiting for them to be available.

Comment: Also, maybe you want your scripts to start drawing something before images and such are loaded. I think that react being the main render engine, it should be loaded first to have it ready ASAP, to avoid long blank websites without adding non-react workarounds. Is a matter of taste and how your app is designed, not webpack specifications. EDIT: Oh, just noticed. I don't forgot to add the detail of "before the bundle file" hehe. Nice. I guess I had to detail this better in the answer.

Comment: OK, but if you are server rendering your React app, or at least rendering a static template showing a spinner whilst bundle loads, rather than just a blank page, you obviously need your scripts at the bottom of the body (and honestly I think this is the standard UX best practice, and better for search engine rankings if nothing else, but I respect we all have our preferences, and like you say 100% depends on the particular app and usecase). I just wanted to clarify whether you were recommending that for a technical reason related to webpack I wasn't aware of :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't build your app, pass it to other guy and ask him to integrate apps together then both of apps will use same dependencies. There is possibility both of you are using same dependencies if you will build your app same dependencies will be added again when 2nd person will build app again. You can use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to divide app into multiple modules. It will handle all packages separately and you can import one package into other, while all packages having their independent dependencies.

**According to Lerna**

> Splitting up large codebases into separate independently versioned packages is extremely useful for code sharing. However, making changes across many repositories is messy and difficult to track, and testing across repositories gets complicated really fast.

Comment: Thank you. I've never heard about Lerna. I'll look into it.